# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on Loading initial ramdisk

Tags: boot, 18.04, lts

So I just bought a Dell vostro-3480 laptop shipped with ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I'm struggling with this weird issue in which my laptop gets stuck on boot and says loading initial ramdisk. But surprisingly it boots up without any issue when it is connected to an AC power adapter.

I'm using 4.15.0-1065-oem kernel

I'd be really thankful to anyone who could help me solve this issue.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I have the same issue on Dell Latitude 5491. I couldn't load previous kernels either. I would love to have some help with this!

Comment: I have found the fix, if you have newly installed 18.04 after few days it'll give you an update software notification DO NOT UPDATE , I REPEAT DO NOT UPDATE ! there's a bug in the update which is causing this issue.

Comment: Could you point which update breaks it? That could help fix this bug...

Answer (score 1):

remove the quiet and splash parameters from the kernel command line parameter at boot will solve the problem.

I have the similar issue with dell vostro 3480 for ubuntu 18.04

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`. From the shell:

   ```
   sudo <your favorite editor> /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Find the line

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```
3. Change it as

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
   ```

   and save.
4. From the shell run

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```